# Using counter within database

Tags: counters, datatool

I try to add a countervalue into a database. But if the database content will be printed, the value is allways the maximum value. I have a simple code example

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{testDB}
\newcounter{couter1}

\begin{document}

    %first row
    \setcounter{couter1}{1}
    \DTLnewrow{testDB}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field1}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%
    \stepcounter{couter1}
    \DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field2}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%

    %second row
    \stepcounter{couter1}
    \DTLnewrow{testDB}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field1}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%
    \stepcounter{couter1}
    \DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field2}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%


    %display content of the database
    \DTLdisplaydb{testDB}

\end{document}
```

The result shuld just look like:

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 5.1 explains that values given as arguments to `\DTLnewdbentry` are not expanded, so you get `cnt: \arabic{couter1}` in all cases. But the manual also suggests a workaround, with `\dtlexpandnewvalue` and `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{testDB}
\newcounter{couter1}

\begin{document}

%first row
\setcounter{couter1}{1}
% we want to expand values
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewrow{testDB}%
\DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field1}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%
\stepcounter{couter1}
\DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field2}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%

%second row
\stepcounter{couter1}
\DTLnewrow{testDB}%
\DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field1}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%
\stepcounter{couter1}
\DTLnewdbentry{testDB}{Field2}{cnt: \arabic{couter1}}%
% revert to the default
\dtlnoexpandnewvalue

%display content of the database
\DTLdisplaydb{testDB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be careful that in this way everything will be fully expanded and sometimes this is not wanted. A single control sequence such as `\textbf` can break havoc in this context, but simply preceding it with `\noexpand` will do; a longer (balanced with respect to braces) list of tokens not to be expanded can be given as argument to `\unexpanded`.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is exactly what i was looking for.